# Object Reference not.... At the time of _mscustomerRepository.Insert(customer);

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am working on Nopcommerce 2.40 .I have created new table ,its class and mapping in project

class code

```
namespace Nop.Core.Domain.Customers
{
   public partial class MSCustomer:BaseEntity
    {


       public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual string Address { get; set; }

       public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

       public virtual string ComapnyName { get; set; }


        public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Below is my mapping

```
 public partial class MSCustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MSCustomer>
    {
        public MSCustomerMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("MSCustomer");
            this.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            this.Property(u => u.Name).HasMaxLength(1000);
            this.Property(u => u.Address).HasMaxLength(1000);
            this.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(100);
            this.Property(c => c.PhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(100);
            this.Property(c => c.CompanyName).HasMaxLength(100);

        }
    }



public virtual void CreateCustomer(MSCustomer customer)
        {
            if (customer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cutomer");

            _mscustomerRepository.Insert(customer);

            //event notification
            _eventPublisher.EntityUpdated(customer);

        }
```

I have created "MScustomer" table in database but at the time of insertion its throwing error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

In Controller I am assigning values to property and passing customer class to insert method.
Is there any solutions.

It throws exception at the  _mscustomerRepository.Insert(customer);

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What made you think that - with all the code you posted - the code where the error actually happens wasn't relevant?

Comment: Where is `_mscustomerRepository` initialized?

Comment: Ohhhhh thanx ,I am going to kill myself, I forgot to initialize _mscustomerRepository